# Meaning of Play Application class

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm developing a project using Play and I'm confused about `Application` class. I see it in many code snippets, for example:

`class Application(silhouette: Silhouette[DefaultEnv]) extends Controller`

([source](https://www.silhouette.rocks/docs/endpoints))

But I don't get if it's an arbitrary name for a generic controller (used instead of `FooController`, `MyController`...) or if it has a special meaning and it gets handled by the framework in a special way.
To add further confusion, I realized that there is also the `Application` interface ([source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/java/play/Application.html)) and the concrete implementation is `DefaultApplication` ([source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/java/play/DefaultApplication.html)) and documentation says:

> Application creation is handled by the framework engine.

so... what is the meaning of having an `Application` controller?

Comment: Hi! I can't tell you the specific answer because I'm also not sure. But I don't think it's a generic controller name, in my play project it is used for the Routes and setting those up properly. The way it is set up in my project, it looks like this though: class Application extends Controller with ControllerUtil . I think the easiest for you, would just be to go check Play project examples of the specific play version you're working in. Especially as they differ quite a bit between the different versions

Answer (score 0):

This is just an arbitrary, generic name as its example. Imagine you are writing a documentation. As an example controller name, you maybe name it as `Application`, `ApplicationController`, `MyApp`, `MyAppController` or `MainController` etc.

But `DefaultApplication` you found on play documentation has meaning.
It is a default implementation of `play.Application` interface (in scala, `play.api.Application` trait) that maneges the play application environment and state etc.

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaApplication
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaApplication

As long as you place controllers under `controllers` namespace, you can name your controllers whatever you want such as "Application".

By the way, default controller from official play template was named as `Application` previously. I guess this is a reason why you see many controller code snippets named `Application`.

- https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-hello-play-scala/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.scala